# Apache keeps an active worker for each WebSocket connection

Tags: apache, websocket, apache2, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-wstunnel

Having Apache (2.4.29) configured as reverse proxy for WebSocket requests with `mod-proxy-wstunnel`:

```
ProxyPass "/myapp/ws" "ws://localhost:8080/myapp/ws"
```

For each active WebSocket client, I see an Apache worker that remains active (in "Sending Reply" status) as long as this client is kept alive even if there is no data being sent. In practice it means I cannot scale WebSocket clients because all available connections are consumed.

In /server-status there is one line like this for each client:

```
Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  Protocol    VHost   Request
0-0 10219   0/43/43 _   1.04    1828    984237  0.0 0.09    0.09    ::1 http/1.1    butler.openbravo.com:443    GET /myapp/ws/helloWs HTTP/1.1
```

Using different `mpm` configurations (tested with event, worker and prefork) has no effect on this.

I would need Apache to be able to reuse these workers when they are sitting idle (no transferring any data) in order to be able to scale it. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I have not :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to multiplex websockets connections this way.

In httpd trunk (2.5.x) there are experimental options to allow these connections to go asynchronous after idle for some time.  But it is unlikely to be something that would be backported to 2.4.x and there is not really a stable 2.6.x on the horizon at the moment.

Comment: I should add that I believe the multiplexing explicitly asked about is simply not possible because it's impossible to reverse map where the traffic goes since the payloads are completely arbitrary.